# Are there any supplements for chinese mages in dark ages?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, dark-ages-mage

I was thinking of trying running a one shot for Mage taking place in China during 13th century however I seem unable to find any supplement describing mages that were at China. I do not wish to use the modern sphere system unless I have to. So what I want to ask is are there any supplements to dark ages that describe chinese mages with pillars and such during dark ages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There aren’t.

There were only two books for **Dark Ages: Mage**, and neither of them addressed magical traditions from that area.

Comment: The closest you'll find is the Akashic Brotherhood or the Order of Hermes clan books, as both have histories involve Asia.  The Dragons of the East book also touches very lightly on it, but doesn't give anything significant (couldn't find a link to the book).
https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/295/Tradition-Book-Akashic-Brotherhood-rev
https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/304/Tradition-Book-Order-of-Hermes-rev